# Script for displaying current date in a text file?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have been trying to make a script in Linux bash that first lists all the files and folders in the homedirectory and then saves the information in a text file with the current date within the textile. So far I have tried this, but the textile is empty:

```
#! /bin/bash
ls -l /home/user/*/
ls /home/user/*/ > list.txt
today=`date '+%d:%m:%Y'`;
touch "$today.list.txt"
```

Comment: So you have a file `list.txt` with the listing, and an empty file <date>`.list.txt`. What was your original intention?

Comment: `ls /home/user/*/ > $(date '+%d:%m:%Y').list.txt`

Comment: To have (date)_list.txt with the list of files and folders that are in the homedirectory

Comment: @PaulHodges Thanks I added that ls /home/user/*/ > $(date '+%d:%m:%Y').list.txt and it did the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version:

```sh
#!/bin/bash    
today=`date '+%d:%m:%Y'`
# we use the $HOME variable and use tee to print and write to the file  
ls $HOME | tee "$today.list.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this

```
#! /bin/bash

#List all files in home directory
ls -l ~/

#store datetime in a variable 
vartime=`date '+%d:%m:%Y'`

#store all filenames in a variable called list
list=$(ls -l ~/)

#create a variable which contains the name of the file to write to
filename=$vartime+".list.txt"

#Append time to the date.list.txt file
echo "$vartime" >> $filename

#Append the list to the date.list.txt file
echo "$list" >> $filename
```

Hope this helped

Comment: This seems like it would put a mess in the file... Put quotes around your vars.

Comment: I also recommend `vartime="$( date '+%d:%m:%Y' )"` instead of backticks...